# Free alternative to LiveReload or LiveStyle that works with Stylus

Tags: gratis, web-development, live-preview

Is there a free alternative to http://livereload.com/ or http://livestyle.emmet.io/? One that possibly work with [stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is
[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io)'s
[Dev Server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

> The webpack-dev-server is a little node.js Express server, which uses the webpack-dev-middleware to serve a webpack bundle. It also has a little runtime which is connected to the server via Socket.IO. The server emits information about the compilation state to the client, which reacts to those events.
>
> ## Automatic Refresh
>
> The webpack-dev-server supports multiple modes to automatic refresh the page
>
> Each mode also supports [Hot Module Replacement](http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html) in which the bundle is notified that a change happened instead of a full page reload. A Hot Module Replacement runtime could then load the updated modules and inject them into the running app

Answer (score 0):

[BrowserSync](http://www.browsersync.io) is exactly the free alternative to LiveReload I've been looking for.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You may download unlimited trial version of LiveReload from their website:
http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/67441-how-do-i-start-using-livereload

It has no restrictions and version is up to date.